# How can I put a smaller div's border-bottom on top of another bigger div's border-bottom?

Tags: html, css, border

I simply have 1 smaller div (navigation menu) in a bigger div (header).

And i need the border-bottom of the smaller div to be on the same height as the border-bottom of the bigger div.

I've attached to pictures:

[have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJEvF.png)

[want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StExX.png)

```css
.main-navigation-link .main-navigation-link-text {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #F18000;
  color: #F18000;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav-main {
    border-bottom: 7px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-main fixed-header">              
  <div class="main-navigation" id="mainNavigation" data-flyout-menu="true">
    <div class="container">
    <nav class="nav main-navigation-menu">

        <a class="nav-link main-navigation-link">
            <div class="main-navigation-link-text">
                <span itemprop="name">Dönermesser</span>
            </div>
        </a>

    </nav>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3b6oukzn/)**

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The easiest way to do that is to use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) (icon looks like <> in the toolbar).

Comment: Pls attach your code, not images, so we can try to help you :)

Comment: @NikolaPavicevic https://jsfiddle.net/3b6oukzn/

Comment: @MattHamer5 https://jsfiddle.net/3b6oukzn/ i tried copy and pasting just the necessary things

Comment: check my answer now pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set margin on smaller div `margin-bottom: -5px;` (or value of border thickness of bigger div)

```css
  .main-navigation-link .main-navigation-link-text {
    border-bottom: 6px solid #F18000;
    color: #F18000;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
  }

  .nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
.nav-main {
    border-bottom: 6px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-main fixed-header"> 
  <div class="main-navigation" id="mainNavigation" data-flyout-menu="true">
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="nav main-navigation-menu">
        <a class="nav-link main-navigation-link">
            <div class="main-navigation-link-text">
                <span itemprop="name">Dönermesser</span>
            </div>
        </a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked, i tried it before with margin.. but it wasn't working
Maybe i had it on the wrong div

Answer (score 0):

You can use :after element on the element with text.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px; /* demo only */
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: orange;
}

.content:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: orange;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">Dönermesser</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already got it working, but thanks for your answer! have a nice day